# Import for custom class in XbaseCompiler

Tags: xtext, xbase

I'm writing a DSL using XBase, and I've added  a new parser rule which returns an `XExpression` in the grammar:

```
DatastepExpression returns xbase::XExpression: {DatastepExpression} 'data' name=ID '{' '}';
```

and added the appropriate function to the `XbaseTypeComputer` subclass:

```
protected def _computeTypes(DatastepExpression expression, ITypeComputationState state) {
    var type = getTypeForName(typeof(FileDataset), state)
    state.acceptActualType(type)
}
```

Now I'm trying to add in the method to the XbaseCompiler subclass:

```
override protected doInternalToJavaStatement(XExpression expr, ITreeAppendable it, boolean isReferenced) {
    switch expr {
        DatastepExpression: {
            newLine
            append('''FileDataset «expr.name»;''')
        }
        default:
            super.doInternalToJavaStatement(expr, it, isReferenced)
    }
}
```

where `FileDataset` is a custom class in my language API.
How do I get this class to appear in the imports at the top of the generated files?

At the moment, when I create a new file in my language (in the runtime Eclipse) the generated Java file contains the `FileDataset` variable declaration but it has a red wavy line underneath and error "FileDataset cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ITreeAppendable` has methods to append instances of `Class`, `JvmType` or `LightweightTypeReference`. A plain

```
it.append(FileDataset).append(' ').append(expr.name)
```

should do the trick.